# A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, php

I have websites on a lot of servers. But on every server, I use one website to cross domain requests with ajax. In php file, where is allowed acces I have this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

In Javascript I have something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/request.php?check=' + request, function(data) {
...
```

On servers, it works fine, but when I am on localhost, I get this in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [request]. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8102' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you could put the requesting domain in the header by parsing `$_SERVER['REFERER']` ...

Comment: Sorry, but `$_SERVER['REFERER']` is `undefined` on web.